# Is there a way to bypass Chrome desktopCapture's Choose Media Screen?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, webrtc, screen-recording, desktopcapturer

I am using Chrome desktopCapture API to create a screen recording Chrome App.

Currently, I am doing this:

---

app.js:

```
    document.querySelector('#startRecording').addEventListener('click', recordClick);
    
    function recordClick(event) {
        console.log("Start Button clicked");
        pending_request_id = chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen"], accessToRecord);
    }

function accessToRecord(id, options){
    if (!id) {
        console.log('Access rejected.');
        return;
    }

    let audioConstraint = {
        mandatory: {
          chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
          chromeMediaSourceId: id
        }
    };
  
    console.log(options.canRequestAudioTrack);

    if (!options.canRequestAudioTrack)
      audioConstraint = false;
    //console.log("id is: "+id);

    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({
        audio : audioConstraint,
        video : {
            mandatory: {
                chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
                chromeMediaSourceId: id,
                maxWidth:screen.width,
                maxHeight:screen.height
            }
        }
    }, startStream, failedStream);
}
```

---

background.js:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  console.log("Launch Link Clicked");
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    bounds: {
      width: 800,
      height: 600
    }
  });
});
```

---

manifest.json:

```
{
    "manifest_version" : 2,
    "name" : "My Screen Recorder",
    "description" : "Allows screen recording",
    "version" : "1",
   "app" : {
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"]
    }
   },    
   "permissions" : ["desktopCapture"]
}
```

---

Behavior this creates on UI:

1. I click on my Chrome App and it shows me a "Start Recording" button(id=startRecording used in above code).
   [Start Recording button - custom screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXDG3.png)
2. Once I clock on this button it shows me this Google screen to select what I want to record:
   [Google's Choose media prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtkzB.png)
3. Then I start using this screen.

---

What I want to achieve:
A way to bypass this Google generated screen to choose the Media to be recorded. I want to pass the media type in my code and on clicking the first "Start Recording" button, I want it to start recording the type I passed in code and not show me the Choose media prompt.

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Looking for the same. it's poor UX to always have that ugly popup.

Comment: Ya, that's my main reason too @bhagyashingale. Please comment if you find anything.

Comment: So an extension called awesome screenshot manages to bypass that. I think webRTC is used and not the chrome api's. Keep me in the loop if you solve it using that.

Answer (score 1):

No, for security reasons—Chrome doesn't want any tool to be able to access sensitive data from outside the browser. You may, however, capture the current tab without prompting with [`chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-captureVisibleTab).

Comment: re "*No*" (for security); Citation needed.